# Custom clipboardData datatype across browsers

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, clipboard, copy-paste

We're trying to allow our users to copy-paste data between two systems. From a webpage to an Electron app.

The user will click a button on which we trigger a copy event with the help of [copy-to-clipboard](https://www.npmjs.com/package/copy-to-clipboard).

```
import copy from "copy-to-clipboard";

const copyHandler = (evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault();

    evt.clipboardData.setData("text/plain", url);
    evt.clipboardData.setData("mumbo/jumbo", JSON.stringify({
        foo: "bar"
    }));
}

document.addEventListener("copy", copyHandler);
copy();
document.removeEventListener("copy", copyHandler);
```

In the Electron app we listen to the paste event:

```
onPaste = (evt) => {
    if(evt.clipboardData.getData("mumbo/jumbo")) {
        // Handle custom data-type
    } else if(evt.clipboardData.getData("text/html")) {
        // Handle html
    } else {
        // Handle plain text
    }
}
```

When the user uses our webpage in Chrome everything works. We can read the data for the custom data-type. But when the user visits the webpage in Firefox `evt.clipboardData.getData("mumbo/jumbo")` will return undefined. The data we set for `text/plain` and `text/html` will still be available.

If we paste the data back to Firefox `evt.clipboardData.getData("mumbo/jumbo")` will properly return the data we set.

I've tried finding information about if this is even supposed to work, but can't find anything. Is custom clipboardData data types supported between browsers at all, and I'm doing something wrong? Or was it never going to work?

Doing the same thing with `application/json` data type also does not work between Firefox and Electron. The only data types we've been able to get to work is `text/plain` and `text/html`, but both are already used for other purposes.

Comment: It seems that firefox has a very basic implementation of copy-paste interaction, i would suggest maybe including xml identifiers in the paste if you need to identify it cross-browser/platform.

Answer (score 3):

In the end I went through all data types listed in [clipboard W3C Working Draft](https://www.w3.org/TR/clipboard-apis/#reading-from-clipboard). At this point I can only get `text/plain` and `text/html` to work when copy-pasting between Firefox and Chrome.

I ended up using `text/html` to pass the data:

```
const copyHandler = (evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault();

    evt.clipboardData.setData("text/plain", url);
    evt.clipboardData.setData("text/html", `<div id="${btoa("mumbo/jumbo")}" data-foo="${bar}"></div>`);
}
```

I Base64 encode the ID with `btoa()` to try to minimise conflicts with regular HTML pastes.